# Change width of barplot from center of bar using base graphics

Tags: r, graphics

I would like to overlay two barplots that use the same scale. I would like the second barplot to be overlayed on the first with skinnier bars to convey how the second metric compares to the first. I do not want to use `ggplot` as it is noticeably slower for this application and I don't want my package to depend on it.

This is what I've started with:

```
set.seed(100)
x <- -5:5
z <- x + rnorm(x, 0, 0.5)

xlim <- range(c(x, z)) * c(0.9, 1.1)

barplot(x, horiz=TRUE, xlim = xlim)
par(new=TRUE)
barplot(z, horiz=TRUE, col="red", xlim = xlim)
```

[image: Plot1]

Reading the docs, it seems like a combination of `space` and `width` can accomplish what I'm trying to do, but I'm not clever enough to figure out the offset needed to make the bar width change from the center rather than from the edge:

```
barplot(x, horiz=TRUE, xlim = xlim)
par(new=TRUE)
barplot(z, horiz=TRUE, width=0.5, space=1, col="red", xlim = xlim)
```

[image: plot2]

Notice that the red bars are offset first from below and then from above. How can I change the width of the bars in the second plot yet keep them centered over the first?